How to add a relationship to an existing mapping class from another module
I have two modules. The first one is:
# module_1.py
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class User(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]

and the second one is:
# module_2.py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column

from .module_1 import Base, User

class Address(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    city: Mapped[str]
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False
    )

    user: Mapped['User'] = relationship(back_populates='addresses')

Now the problem is I don't know how to add
addresses: Mapped[Set['Address']] = relationship(back_populates='user')

to the User class from inside module_2.py without modifying module_1.py file. By the way, I don't want to use the legacy backref relationship parameter.

You can try to add addresses relationship to the User class after its definition:
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Mapped, mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm.base import class_mapper
from sqlalchemy.orm.relationships import RelationshipProperty

from .module_1 import Base, User

class Address(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    city: Mapped[str]
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False
    )

    user: Mapped['User'] = relationship(back_populates='addresses')

mapper = class_mapper(User)
mapper.add_property(
    'addresses',
    relationship(
        Address,
        back_populates='user',
        uselist=True
    )
)

or adapt the User class by inheriting from it, make modifications as needed, and then utilize it. Something like how DeclarativeBase is used.

Thanks. It works. The only problem is code completion does not work, and thus cannot detect that addresses is a member of User.

@Dante Yeah, same problem. I haven't found how to deal with this.
